# Как приложения, написанные на C#, выполняются на Андроид?

Tags: c#, android, .net

Допустим, есть приложение, написанное с использованием C# MAUI под Андроид. Как тогда оно работает на Андроид? На Андроид должно быть подобие CLR, или дела обстоят по-другому? А также как работают игры, написанные с использованием Unity, на Андроид?

Comment: Достаточно прочитать [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui?view=net-maui-8.0#how-net-maui-works)...